# Timer Interrupt Default Settings

Tags: interrupt, timers

so I am testing out the PulseSensor code from here: https://github.com/WorldFamousElectronics/PulseSensorAmped_2_Sensors/tree/master/PulseSensorAmped_2_Sensors_1.5.0

In the interrupt.ino file, there is a function interruptSetup() which initializes the timer settings. However, I want to undo these settings first, as I have found out that this function is affecting my other readings. What is the default settings for the timer?

Comment: Unless you are using PWM, you can just set all these registers to zero. Otherwise, see [Arduino's init() function](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L241).

Comment: Is the init() function the default settings for the timer?